# Update multiple nodes and increment value by 1 in atomic style

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to update my code and implement another child update to a node by increasing its value by 1. My current code looks like this (which works fine):

```
String key = database.child("rides").push().getKey();

Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
childUpdates.put("/rides/" + key, ride.toMap());
childUpdates.put("/ridesUser/" + ride.getUserID() + "/ownRides/" + key, ride.getTime());

database.updateChildren(childUpdates, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
    }
});
```

An easy way to add the increment code would be:

```
childUpdates.put("/stations/" + ride.getFromID() + "/rideCount", fromStation.getRideCount() + 1);
```

But `fromStation.getRideCount()` could already be outdated, if another user added a ride with this station.
I've read several posts about incrementing values by using a transaction. How can I combine child updates and transactions? Should I run a transaction on `"/stations/" + ride.getFromID()` and do my children updates within the `doTransaction()` method? Is this atomically?

Answer (score 3):

If you've read several posts, you might have seen this already: it is not possible to combine multi-location updates and transactions.

Your options:

1. do a transaction at the lowest common level in the tree
2. use security rules to implement pseudo-transactions for your multi-location update. See [this answer from Kato](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22971571/how-do-i-prevent-duplicate-voting-while-incrementing-the-vote-count-on-firebase) or [this more recent answer from me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954217/is-the-way-the-firebase-database-quickstart-handles-counts-secure)
3. write the "change record" from the client and then let a server (which is less likely to face contention) do the update transactionally. See for example my answer to this question: [When should you use Firebase Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111370/when-should-you-use-firebase-transactions)