# Google Firebase Realtime Database setValue IF (condition)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Firebase database:**

```
{
  "balance" : 10
}
```

**Application 1 (pseudocode):**

```
if (balance-10 >= 0)
{
    // Application freezes for a few seconds. (Connection/hardware issue or whatever reason)
    balance -= 10;
}
```

**Application 2 (pseudocode):**

```
if (balance-10 >= 0)
{
    // Application is executed without any problems.
    balance -= 10;
}
```

If both applications start at the same time, the final "balance" value will be "-10" instead of "0".

In MySQL this problem is easy fixed by:

> UPDATE `table` SET balance=IF(balance-10>=0, balance-10, balance);

What are the possible solutions for Firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is handled through [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions). Since you don't specify what technology I'm showing the web code:

```
balanceRef.transaction(function(current) {
  if (current && current > 10) {
    return current - 10;
  }
  return (current || 0);
}
```

If multiple applications run this code at the same time, one of them will get its transaction rejected and will retry.

Also see:

- [When should you use Firebase Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111370/when-should-you-use-firebase-transactions/38112152#38112152)
- [Firebase runTransaction not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818946/firebase-runtransaction-not-working/35819073#35819073)
- [How can I use a transaction while performing a multi-location update in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297884/how-can-i-use-a-transaction-while-performing-a-multi-location-update-in-firebase/39298597#39298597)

Comment: It works perfectly, I also had a problem with the first `doTransation` call, which return `null` and your 2nd url helped me. Thanks. (Java btw)